# How can I change capital letters to small letters and vice versa in strings, without using string commands and acii code

Tags: c

I have to write the function that deletes every char from the text that isn't a number,changes first letter of every word to capital letter and changes rest letters to small letters.

The problem is that :

- I can't use ctype, stdlib and string library
- I can use only scanf when I want to input
- I can't use [] operator except for the array declaration
- I can't use digits except for 0 and 1

Normally it would be easy but with those conditions, I have no idea how to do it. I'm new into strings, don't be harsh :).

Comment: this sounds like a homework problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You might want to look at the difference in ASCII values for lowercase and uppercase characters since it's constant. Not being able to use digits is weird, but you could express that difference as a `char`

Comment: 'function that deletes every char from the text that isn't a number' then how are you supposed to 'change first letter of every word to capital letter and changes rest letters to small letters'?

Comment: The problem is normally I would do this type of exercise with acii code. But here I have no idea even how to start this. @ReticulatedSpline How can I express 32 as char w/o using 3 and 2 ?

Comment: @ice592 `10+10+10+1+1`? Or simply `' '`. Or `'a' - 'A'`, if you want "speaking" code

Comment: The restriction on the [] operator means you need to use a pointer to traverse the array, e.g. `for (ptr = input; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)`

Comment: @user3386109 But then I have to do this for all letter and vive versa 'A' - 'a'. I think there must be better way.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Ctx This seems so dumb but I cannot find other solution for now , so thanks

Comment: `if (*ptr >= 'A' && *ptr <= 'Z') *ptr += 'a' - 'A';` changes an upper case letter to a lower case letter (assuming letters are encoded as ASCII). `'a' - 'A'` is just a different way to write 32 (again assuming ASCII encoding).

Comment: @ice592 note that all three versions I mentioned result in exactly the same assembler code (since all three will be the constant integer 32 at _compile time_), so use what is best understandable. There is no performance penalty with any version.

Comment: @user3386109 I didn't know that I can use 'A' same as '65' when it comes to comparing

Comment: Yup, character constants like `'A'` are just integers. You can use them anywhere that you would use an integer constant, e.g. `printf("%d\n", 'A');`

Comment: ice592 "seems so dumb but I cannot find other solution for now" --> Rather than look for a solution, try writing your own.  Post it if you have troubles.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try to make some macros like this:

```
#define IS_UPPER(c) ( (c) >= 'A' && (c) <= 'Z' )
#define IS_LOWER(c) ( (c) >= 'a' && (c) <= 'z')
#define TO_UPPER(c) ( (c) -= ('a' - 'A'))
#define TO_LOWER(c) ( (c) += ('a' - 'A'))

#define IS_ALPHA(c) ( IS_UPPER(c) || IS_LOWER(c) )
```

And see if you can make something work

```
void homework(char * txt)
{
    while(*txt != NUL)
    {
        /* do some stuff */

        txt++;
    }
}
```